# How can I pass multiple elements from a collection into a function with one or more of the elements being mutable?

Tags: vector, collections, rust

When passing two elements from the same vector to a function, the borrow checker will not allow one of the elements to be mutable.

```
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<Point> = Vec::new();
    foo(&mut vec[0], &vec[1]);
}
fn foo(pnt_1: &mut Point, pnt_2: &Point) {
}
```

> error: cannot borrow `vec` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

`vec` is never borrowed by `foo` though, `vec[0]` is borrowed and `vec[0]` is a `Point`.

How can I pass multiple elements from the same collection into a function with one or more of the elements being mutable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I pass multiple elements from the same collection into a function with one or more of the elements being mutable?

The short answer is that you cannot, at least not without support from the collection itself.

Rust disallows *mutable aliases* - multiple names for the same thing, one of which allows mutation.

It would be far too complicated (with the current state of programming languages) to verify that `(&mut vec[0], &vec[1])` does not introduce aliasing but `(&mut vec[0], &vec[0])` does. Adding to the complexity is the fact that the `[]` operator can be overloaded, which allows creating a type such that `foo[0]` and `foo[1]` actually point *at the same thing*.

So, how can a collection help out? Each collection will have (or not have) a specific way of subdivision in an aliasing-safe manner.

There can be methods like [`slice::split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) which verify that that two halves cannot overlap and thus no aliasing can occur.

Unfortunately, there's no `HashMap::get_two_things(&a, &b)` that I'm aware of. It would be pretty niche, but that doesn't mean it *couldn't* exist.

> `vec` is never borrowed by `foo` though

It most certainly is. When you index a `Vec`, you are getting a reference to some chunk of memory inside the `Vec`. If the `Vec` were to change underneath you, such as when *someone adds or removes a value*, then the underlying memory may need to be reallocated, invalidating the reference. This is a prime example of why mutable aliasing is a bad thing.

Comment: No `HashMap::get_two_things(&a, &b)`, oh man! I need to rethink my data structures. I'm really enjoying Rust, but I wonder if it is really as fast as C with all of these workarounds you need to implement.

Comment: @HiDefender beware the [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Often, a problem can be solved in a different way that is both idiomatic and performant. That applies for most languages, not just Rust! It's reasonable to ask a question one step up that you think might be solved by "multiple elements from a collection, one mutable", but allow the community more leeway in solutions. Normal question rules apply of course - create an [MCVE] and show research.

Comment: @HiDefender: Rust is not "as fast as C", it's [**faster**](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)! While aliasing is used for safety at the moment, it can also be used for performance. The main reason that Fortran kernels for numeric libraries are still in use today is because they are faster than the C and C++ kernels. And why are they faster? Because Fortran is stricter about aliasing, giving more opportunity to the compiler for optimization.